# (AS3) Fixing Frogger Game ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having 10 errors (1120) associated with the access of undefined property. 
onEnterFrame, onClick, onLeftClick, MouseUp, onUpClick, MouseUp, onDownClick, MouseUp, onRightClick, and MouseUp.

The Errors are being thrown from the .addEventListener fron lines 58 to 73

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class FrogKatta extends MovieClip
    {
        // Create instances of library symbols 
        var car1:Car = new Car();
        var car2:Car = new Car();
        var truck1:Truck = new Truck();
        var truck2:Truck = new Truck();
        var frog:Frog = new Frog();
        var FinishLine:finishLine = new finishLine();
        var HealthBar:healthBar = new healthBar();
        var vx:int = 0;
        var vy:int = 0;

        var hit:Boolean = false;
        var carStart:Boolean = false;
        var truckStart:Boolean = false;



        public function frogKatta()
        {
            frog.x = 230;
            frog.y = 375;

            truck1.x = 545;
            truck1.y = 230;

            truck2.x = 560;
            truck2.y = 235;

            car1.x = 550;
            car1.y = 78;

            car2.x = 560;
            car2.y = 80;

            // add created instances to stage 
            addChild(frog);
            addChild(truck1);
            addChild(truck2);
            addChild(car1);
            addChild(car2);
            // * PROBLEM WITH STAGE.ADDEVENTLISTENER
            // Add event listener for keyboard 

// PROBLEM STARTS HERE ***********


            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);


            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

            // Add Event for mouse click 
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            // creating instance of onClick from the MouseEvent.CLICK
            //Keyboard 
            left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLeftClick);
            // to move
            left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
            // to stop 
            up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onUpClick);
            up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
            down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownClick);
            down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
            right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onRightClick);
            right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);

//  PROBLEM ENDS HERE****


            // Keyboard functionality 
            function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
                {
                    vx = -5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
                {
                    vx = 5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
                {
                    vy = 5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                {
                    vy = -5;
                    frog.play();
                }
            }

            // Keyboard again to stop 
            function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
                {
                    vx = 0;
                    frog.stop();
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                {
                    vy = 0;
                    frog.stop();
                }

                // Clicking Functionality
                function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    vy = 0;
                    vx = 0;
                    frog.stop();
                }
                // on"librarybutton name left" Click
                function onLeftClick(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    vx = -5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                function onUpClick(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    vy = -5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                function onDownClick(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    vy = 5;
                    frog.play();
                }
                function onRightClick(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    vx = 5;
                    frog.play();
                }


                // on enter frame 
                function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
                {
                    frog.x +=  vx;
                    frog.y +=  vy;

                    truck1.x +=  -10;
                    car1.x +=  -20;


                    //Car1 & 2 SCREEN WRAPPING 
                    if (car1.x <= -400)
                    {
                        car1.x = 550;
                    }
                    // If car 1 leaves screen add car to other side of the screen

                    if (car2.x <= -400)
                    {
                        car2.x = 550;
                    }

                    if (car1.x <= 135)
                    {
                        carStart = true;
                    }
                    // Screen wrap so if car is less than or equal to 135 in distance add another car 

                    if (carStart)
                    {
                        car2.x +=  -15;
                    }

                    //Truck1 & 2 
                    if (truck1.x <= -400)
                    {
                        truck1.x = 550;
                    }

                    if (truck2.x <= -400)
                    {
                        truck2.x = 550;
                    }


                    if (truck1.x <= 135)
                    {
                        truckStart = true;

                    }

                    if (truckStart)
                    {
                        truck2.x +=  -10;

                    }
                    if (frog.hitTestObject(truck1) || frog.hitTestObject(truck2) || frog.hitTestObject(car1) || frog.hitTestObject(car2))
                    {
                        frog.y +=  10;
                        hit = true;

                    }
                    if (hit)
                    {
                        if (HealthBar.width < 10)
                        {
                            HealthBar.width = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HealthBar.width -=  10;
                        }
                    }

                    if (HealthBar.width < 1)
                    {
                        //S.O.P you lose);
                    }




                    if (frog.hitTestObject(FinishLine))
                    {

                        removeChild(frog);
                        removeChild(FinishLine);
                        removeChild(car1);
                        removeChild(car2);
                        removeChild(truck1);
                        removeChild(truck2);
                        // addchild of you winning

                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a brackets issue I believe.

You need a '}' right before your onKeyDown function.

Check all your brackets, you might also have an extra one at the end of the file, after you insert the one where I told you.

These lines are an issue, because up/down/left/right are not present in your code. If they are stage instances, they are likely not named, therefore your code will not be able to use them. Name the instances via the property panel if that is the case.

```
    left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLeftClick);
    // to move
    left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
    // to stop 
    up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onUpClick);
    up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
    down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDownClick);
    down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
    right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onRightClick);
    right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);
```

You also have another bracket issue in not closing your onKeyUp function.

That is causing it to think all your event handlers are in that function.

But as I said in my comment, this is really not a debug your application forum.

Please take the time to verify your brackets as I requested. It doesn't show much appreciation for someone's time, when you aren't taking the time to check something that has been found to be an issue. Please, take the time to verify all your brackets for each function, and you will save yourself alot of time.

Comment: I fixed that issue, It still doesn't work, any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting the same errors ? Is this your document class ?

Comment: Did you verify that you have the same amount of open/close brackets ? As I said, you need to verify that aspect.

Comment: Yes for both, If i may have your email I can send you screenshots of it.

Comment: I believe I have the correct number because If I subtract one i get a error saying im missing a bracket

Comment: When I test the movie nothing happens at all..Thats why i am curious what is going on..I dont think its the brackets. I can send you screenshots/the flash file for you to look at it..if you can please.

Comment: The brackets were just the first issue. You have more problems. But this is not a debug your application for you forum. I'll add a few more to the answer, but really you need to have one question per post. "What are all the problems with my code?" is not a valid question.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Yes, I found another bracket issue. Please take the time to verify all your brackets. I found another issue that I detailed. Please break your issues down into individual questions, not one big "debug my application" thread such as this.

Comment: Okay I understand; sorry im a bit new to this forum. I have actually been trying to fix this for a while and still nothing has worked. If it would be possible im willing to contact you outside this forum for help w/ this assignment plus one other and have no problem paying for tutoring. My email is: survivantny@gmail.com